# Term for listing vertices of polygon in consecutive order

Tags: terminology, plane-geometry

If I have a polygon with vertices in some order $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n$, then the order may be such that $\overline{P_i P_{i+1}}$ is an edge of the polygon for each $i$, or they could be in some random order with no relation to the edges.

Is there an established term for the former case?

To be concrete, I want to write a sentence of the form "This method returns the vertices in _______ order," or something similar.

I could say something like "consecutive" or "sequential" but I think the meaning there is not quite intuitive.  In the case that the polygon is convex this would be equivalent to saying something like "in either clockwise or counterclockwise order," but I was hoping for something more general and less confusing.

I could also write a long explanation, but I'm hoping for something that's readable and unambiguous and fits in a single sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have the order dependent upon some index, why not "indicial order" or "index order" or "ordered by index?"